# Robolectric Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, robolectric, android-livedata, androidx-test

I am testing an `AsyncTask` that `onPostExecute` calls `setValue` of a `LiveData` instance. Since I am invoking `setValue` from `onPostExecute` no issues were expected regarding the invocation being done by the UI thread.

Yet running this in a Robolectric unit test I got: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread`

To make this unit test wait for background and foreground tasks completion I take advantage of awaitility tool in the following way:

```java
var cf = new CompletableFuture<T>();
livedata.observe(ctrl.get(), it -> cf.complete(it));
// ... perform the AsyncTask that will update livedata in onPostExecute
await().until(() -> {
    flushBackgroundThreadScheduler()
    flushForegroundThreadScheduler()
    cf.isDone
});
```

**This is throwing an `IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread` on `flushForegroundThreadScheduler()` call!!!!**

Why I am getting this exception? And how can I have the `onPostExecute` being performed like in the UI thread?

**UPDATE**

Logging threads it seems that both `flushBackgroundThreadScheduler()` and `flushForegroundThreadScheduler()` are executed synchronously inline. I can observe:

```
LiveData created on thread 763324286
Background thread 1519527121
LiveData updated on thread 1519527121
```

Since the lambda passed to `await.until` runs on another thread, then both `flushBackgroundThreadScheduler()` and `flushForegroundThreadScheduler()` are performed on that thread 1519527121.

Thus, I can solve my problem with the following workaround running in the test thread corresponding to UI Thread. Yet, I need that `Thread.sleep()` to succeed and I don't like it.

```java
Thread.sleep(1000)
flushBackgroundThreadScheduler()
flushForegroundThreadScheduler()
cf.isDone
```

Comment: What is inside `flushForegroundThreadScheduler`?

Comment: @GensaGames I don't get your question. `flushForegroundThreadScheduler` is a method from Robolectric library.

Comment: I think the answer you're looking for is here: https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/01/17/livedatajunit5/

Answer (score 0):

We must have the following considerations into account regarding:

1. Robolectric: `flushForegroundThreadScheduler()` is executed synchronously inline.
2. Awaitility: `await.until(<Callable>)` evaluates the until condition in a background thread.

From these two statements we observe that invoking `flushForegroundThreadScheduler()` from the `Callable` passed to `await.until(<Callable>)` results in the invocation of scheduled foreground tasks in a background thread, which answers the first OP question: *Why I am getting this exception?*

Answering the second OP question:

> how can I have the `onPostExecute` being performed like in the UI thread?

Since Robolectric shares a single thread for both UI operations and Test code, then we must use `pollInSameThread` to instruct that the until condition should be evaluated on the same thread as the test case that starts Awaitility. The OP sample code should be fixed to:

```java
await().pollInSameThread().until(() -> {
    flushBackgroundThreadScheduler()
    flushForegroundThreadScheduler()
    cf.isDone
});
```